# Iterate over a string, but keep the delimiters in sub strings, including other rules

Tags: c++, string, split, iteration, delimiter

I am trying to iterate over a string such that it breaks up into substrings that I append to the end of a vector. Also, I am trying to have a few other rules as well. (apostrophes are considered alphanumeric, if a ',' appears between digits its ok if a '.' appears before a digit/whitespace or between digits its ok)

For example:

```
This'.isatest!!!!andsuch .1,00,0.011#$%@
```

Would come out as:

```
myvector[This'][.][isatest][!!!!][andsuch][.1,00,0.011][#$%@]
```

I have no trouble splitting on nonalphanumeric characters (and apostrophes), and also an if statement for the ',' and '.', but I am running into trouble keeping the delimiters. Currently, I am getting something more like:

```
myvector[This'][.][isatest][!][!][!][!][andsuch][.1,00,0.011][#][$][%][@]
```

Any useful tips?

Comment: Tip1: Mention which programming language you're working in. Preferably put it in a tag as well.

Comment: added it to the tags and the post - thank you

Comment: Do you already know about [`isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) and related functions?

Comment: yes, I use this line of code in a method that accepts characters: return(isalnum(temp) || temp == '\'');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I may be a little bit cuckoo, I spent the time doing an other, hand-rolled, parser in addition to the [previous answer using Boost Spirit to generate it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46295583/85371).

As you can see it's not exactly simpler. It's tedious, error prone, hard to maintain and much less generic. You choose!

> **Pro Tip:** Write code you understand. That gives you the fleeting chance to maintain it.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a3a8f7fe2fa2ab9)</kbd>**

```
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Out>
Out smart_split(char const* first, char const* last, Out out) {
    auto it = first;
    std::string token;

    auto emit = [&] {
        if (!token.empty()) 
            *out++ = token;
        token.clear();
        return out;
    };

    enum { NUMBER_LIST, OTHER } state = OTHER;

    while (it != last) {
#ifndef NDEBUG
        std::cout << std::string(it - first, ' ') << std::string(it, last) << " (token: '" << token << "')\n";
#endif

        if (std::isdigit(*it) || *it == '-' || *it == '+' || *it == '.') {
            if (state != NUMBER_LIST)
                emit();

            char* e;
            std::strtod(it, &e);
            if (it < e) {
                token.append(it, static_cast<char const*>(e));
                it = e;

                if (it != last && *it == ',') {
                    token += *it++;
                    state = NUMBER_LIST;
                }
            } 
            else {
                token += *it++;
            }
        } 
        else if (std::isalpha(*it) || *it == '\'') {
            state = OTHER;
            emit();

            while (it != last && (std::isalpha(*it) || *it == '\'')) {
                token += *it++;
            }

            emit();
        }
        else {
            if (state == NUMBER_LIST)
                emit();
            state = OTHER;
            token += *it++;
        }
    }

    return emit();
}

#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<std::string> Tokens;

int main()
{
    std::string const input = "This'.isatest!!!!andsuch.1,00,0.11#$%@";

    Tokens actual;
    smart_split(input.data(), input.data() + input.size(), back_inserter(actual));

    for (auto& token : actual)
        std::cout << token << "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
This'
.
isatest
!!!!
andsuch
.1,00,0.11
#$%@
```

In the case of DEBUG build, it also traces progress through the loop:

```
This'.isatest!!!!andsuch.1,00,0.11#$%@ (token: '')
     .isatest!!!!andsuch.1,00,0.11#$%@ (token: '')
      isatest!!!!andsuch.1,00,0.11#$%@ (token: '.')
             !!!!andsuch.1,00,0.11#$%@ (token: '')
              !!!andsuch.1,00,0.11#$%@ (token: '!')
               !!andsuch.1,00,0.11#$%@ (token: '!!')
                !andsuch.1,00,0.11#$%@ (token: '!!!')
                 andsuch.1,00,0.11#$%@ (token: '!!!!')
                        .1,00,0.11#$%@ (token: '')
                           00,0.11#$%@ (token: '.1,')
                              0.11#$%@ (token: '.1,00,')
                                  #$%@ (token: '.1,00,0.11')
                                   $%@ (token: '#')
                                    %@ (token: '#$')
                                     @ (token: '#$%')
```

Comment: This totally works and is great! Unfortunately, due to the specifics of my assignment, I had to just force it instead with a bunch of if statements, but I will most likely come back to this for a similar problem in another class...

Comment: Is your if-else forest as dense as mine? I think this nicely dodges it with a modicum of functional style: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8cb27ec21e51a7a (compiled with NDEBUG) while still being standard library only

Answer (score 2):

You want to tokenize, with some domain-specific productions (like: "comma delimited numbers"). My weapon of choice is a parser generator in Boost: Boost Spirit.

> **Note** I've added a [standard-library-only variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46296513/85371)

Here you go:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e561e216f6c5229)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <cassert>

using Tokens = std::vector<std::string>;

Tokens smart_split(std::string const& s) {
    Tokens tokens;

    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

    auto wordc = char_("a-zA-Z'");
    parse(s.begin(), s.end(), *raw [double_%','| +wordc | +~wordc], tokens);

    return tokens;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    Tokens const expected { "This'",".","isatest","!!!!","andsuch",".1,00,0.11","#$%@" };
    Tokens const actual = smart_split("This'.isatest!!!!andsuch.1,00,0.11#$%@");

    for (auto t : actual)
        std::cout << std::quoted(t) << ",";

    assert(actual == expected);
}
```

Prints

```
"This'",".","isatest","!!!!","andsuch",".1,00,0.11","#$%@",
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but is there a way to do something similar in the std library? I am still quite new to c++ so I'd prefer to stick to that until I get my feet under me.

Comment: For completeness: [c++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba578da99ccfef5e) and [c++03](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a34c9ce8e3a8e46) versions

Comment: You can do everything with the standardlibrary. And it will be a lot more difficult. What exact format do you want to support for the numbers? Are spaces significant? Etc.

Comment: The numbers should be treated as letters and apostrophes and the spaces I have already taken out of the line I am reading in.

Comment: What. The numbers should be treated as letters an apostrophes? (That makes no sense at all. Note, you can see from my answer I already knew that part.)

Comment: Sorry, I meant they should all be strings, I am confused by what you meant by format. commas should be considered a delimiter until they are between two digits, in which case they are ignored. For now, I will be doing nothing with the numbers, simply spitting them into a text file.

Comment: You know. Is `.1,00,0.11` one number? Is `3.14,8e-7,-INF,NaN,.,+9` a valid number token. Simple stuff like that. Rule number #1 of software specification: "It's never simple". Rule number #1 of text processing: "Text is not simple".

Comment: And, special courtesy, because it's "all you can eat night": [a standard-library-only version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46296513/85371). Which is more legible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154791/discussion-between-sehe-and-nomim).